# How to cut and group by letter in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
A    B
a0   1
a0-2 2
a1   3
a2   4
a2-2 5
a3   6
a4   7
```

I would like to group below bins

```
          df.B.sum
[a0~a0-2)     3 
[a1~a1-2)     3
[a2~a2-2)     9
[a3~a3-2)     6
[a4~a4-2)     7
```

How this could be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` by `Series` created by [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) by second letter of column `A`:

```
print (df.A.str[1:2].astype(int))
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    4
Name: A, dtype: int32

bins = [-1,0,1,2,5]
labels=['[a0~a0-2)','[a1~a1-2)','[a2~a2-2)','[a3~a4-2)']
s = pd.cut(df.A.str[1:2].astype(int), bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (s)
0    [a0~a0-2)
1    [a0~a0-2)
2    [a1~a1-2)
3    [a2~a2-2)
4    [a2~a2-2)
5    [a3~a4-2)
6    [a3~a4-2)
Name: A, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [[a0~a0-2) < [a1~a1-2) < [a2~a2-2) < [a3~a4-2)]

df = df.groupby(s).B.sum().reset_index()
print (df)
           A   B
0  [a0~a0-2)   3
1  [a1~a1-2)   3
2  [a2~a2-2)   9
3  [a3~a4-2)  13
```

Another similar solution as another answer, only is used [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) function:

```
d = {'a0': '[a0~a0-2)', 
     'a1': '[a1~a1-2)', 
     'a2': '[a2~a2-2)', 
     'a3': '[a3~a4-2)', 
     'a4': '[a3~a4-2)'}
df = df.groupby(df.A.str[:2].map(d)).B.sum().reset_index()
print (df)
           A   B
0  [a0~a0-2)   3
1  [a1~a1-2)   3
2  [a2~a2-2)   9
3  [a3~a4-2)  13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column with the shortened version of you column and then group on this column.

```
# take only the first two characters into the new column
df['group_col'] = df.A.str[:2]
df.groupby('group_col').B.sum()
```

Of course you can be creative when creating the group column.

```
lo = {'a0': 0, 'a1': 1, 'a2': 2, 'a3': 3, 'a4': 3}
df['group_col'] = df.A.str[:2].apply(lambda val: lo[val])
df.groupby('group_col').B.sum()

group_col
0     3
1     3
2     9
3    13
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to group by elements that start with same letter and number, you can use a function in groupby like this :

```
def group_func(i):
    global df
    return df.iloc[i]['A'].split("-")[0]
df.groupby(group_func).sum()
```

otherwise if you want to group every two elements,

```
def group_func(i):
    return i // 2
df.groupby(group_func).sum()
```

Comment: I don't think the intention to group every two elements

Comment: from the example in the question,  a3 and a4 are grouped which had no relation

Comment: I noticed that but with your solution you'd also mix up the groups containing a1 and a2 since there is only one element with a1.

Comment: you are right, I think the problem is from the question, it's not clear enough, I m gonna edit the response, thanks